# Does Haki also eliminate Devil Fruit users' weakness against water?

Tags: one-piece

If Luffy covers his arm with Haki and puts it in the water, will he lose his power or does the Haki cancel the effect of the water?

I thought about it because of this image.

[image]

When Luffy used his "Red Hawk" against Hody, the water had no effect on his power. Is this because of the Haki he used for Red Hawk (which was not well drawn in the anime) or is there another reason?

Answer (score 4):

**Luffy would lose his power**, because Haki does not seem to negate the power of the sea at all. In chapter 603, we could see how Luffy put his hand into the ocean without coating it in Haki. He said to be powerless in the ocean, yet he was able to draw Sanji back to the boat. This would make it seem that due to his training during the time-skip, he has become able to withstand the power of the sea for a short while.

[image]

Then, in chapter 605, we could see how Luffy put his hand back into the ocean, but this time he coated it in Haki. Despite being fully coated, he still lost his power at the same rate. Luffy got a lot stronger during the time-skip and it might even be that, since he has more power to drain, it might take a bit longer, but **it is safe to say that coating yourself in Haki does not negate the effects of the sea**.

[image]

Comment: but earlier we saw when he touches the water, he instantly lost his power. And now after the timeskip he can resist the water just because he is stronger. i believe he can resist because of his haki, but in fact his haki is not that strong jet. So as a matter of fact, the water still drains his power...

Comment: @BBallBoy Yes, the water still drains his power. Isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: yeah but i mean, his haki is still not fully trained. so the water still drains his power but not immediately. so i think, if someone has a very powerful haki, like maybe vergo. he could totally resist the water.

Comment: @BBallBoy Do you have any proof that Haki has any influence on this? Because we have seen Luffy put his hand in the water at other times without Haki and he still didn't lose any of his strength. The effect of the sea was the same regardless of HAki

Comment: @BBallBoy I updated the answer according to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the water that drains them. It's the stagnant non-running water. This is why they can shower and drink water but not take a bath. So if they could vibrate their Haki in a manner which causes the water around them to FLOW like a running water, then in theory they could nullify the effects of the water.

Comment: No, it's the salt that makes the difference. Look at Gecko Moria arc

Comment: thats actually not true. oda himself says otherwise in an interview, a question was asked which was "Odacchi! Here's a question for you! Crocodile can't fight water because he's "sand," right? Then how does he bathe?! Does he at all?! That's filthy!! Do you bathe, Odacchi? oda's response was  First of all, let's discuss the problem of Devil Fruit users bathing themselves. People who have eaten a Devil Fruit are "hated" by the sea, and cannot swim. The "sea" here can refer to anything from rivers, pools and baths to any kind of standing water. On a worldwide level, they are all the "sea."

Comment: Your answer does not contradict mine, but we recall Brook defeating the monsters using salt